# Break auto repair loop with faulty HDD

Tags: windows-10, boot, chkdsk

First of all: my HDD is faulty - it has bad sectors and I know that. All my important data is already backed up and a replacement is ordered, but I need system to boot and perform a simple service that is not HDD-bound right now. Those bad sectors do not multiply and do not affect the files I need to run the service.

Some time ago the system had a dirty shutdown and now endlessly tries to repair the drive in "Automatic Repair" mode. Booting from the installation media, going to command prompt and running `chkdsk c: /f` manually shows that it completes phase 1 and fails upon trying to perform actual repairs with:

```
Failed to transfer logged messages to the event log with status 50.
```

Since `chkdsk` fails to complete, it just restarts and goes into it again.

What can I do to break this cycle?

1. Message seems to suggest that `chkdsk` just wants to do some logging and fails. Can I just disable that?
2. Can I somehow mark volume clean without actually performing any repairs. I don't care if this causes some backlogged data to be lost - as mentioned above, there's nothing important on this HDD.
3. Can I somehow disable automatic repair completely? Boot files should be clean for system just to start up. I've already tried `bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No`, but it still in the loop.

Comment: If it's not HDD bound.... move the service onto another hdd, i.e. swap the HDD in the box? -- You are not going to get windows runnning in a happy state with a hdd that can't do whatever it's trying to do. Using a Linux Live Cd you *might* be able to remove the requirement for the chkdsk at boot, but I'm unsure.

Comment: "replacement is ordered"

Comment: can't you boot in safe mode via F8?

Comment: Can you run the service from a Linux LiveCD or another machine?

Comment: @Burgi, service is Windows-only and requires some setup that I'd rather won't deal with on any "temporary" PC - I'll do it later on new HDD.

Comment: @satibel, it's notoriously hard to get into menu without already fully bootable system since Windows 8. So far it seems F8 is completely ignored.